# Strict variable scoping in R

Tags: r, rlang

I am looking to ensure variables are not pulled from parent environments in R. For instance, I would like to following function to fail.

```
a <- 1
f <- \() a
f()
# 1
```

I have tried

```
local(expr = {
  f()
})
```

and rlang's `locally`. Where I would expect this to fail.

They both seem to still pull up from the parent environment

Comment: Your `local()` example doesn't work for a few reasons. With R's lexical scoping, functions inherit from the environment where they are defined, not where they are called. So since `a` and `f` are defined in the same scope, they will find each other. And even if you defined the function in the local as well, `local()` creates a new environment that inherits from the calling environment so it will still find the `a` variable in the global scope.

Comment: Right so my question is how can I enable strict scoping? Or is that just a feature of the language.

Comment: All those discussions are available at the duplicate link. You can't easily change how the R interpreter resolves variables. you can just choose which workaround is most appropriate for your specific case.